Are pedagogical questions off-topic?
Note: If downvote for meta means no to a yes/no question, then...

Edit: Ah, a downvote. Ok so I guess it's ON-topic.


I am asking because of this
Is it fair in an introductory stochastic calculus/derivatives pricing class to ask for the price when absence of arbitrage is violated?
Sounds like 1 of those soft-questions on maths se or quant se, ethics questions on acad se or work se or a question on maths educator se.
some guide questions:

we don't have a quant education se...we can't possibly have an education se for every single non-education academic se besides academia se if they aren't so popular yet right? i figure maths se and computer science se are so popular that they got their own spin offs. but quant se? did it even graduate yet?

it is closed as opinion-based instead of off-topic. what gives? which is it? is it the wrong close vote?

re opinion based, what about soft-question ?



Years ago, I taught undergraduates (from Shreve volumes I and II, as an adjunct). We definitely discussed in class what to do if the market data (seems to) admit arbitrage. I wouldn't put a question like this on an exam...
I think, questons like "is it fair to ask stuff on the exam that wasn't properly covered in class or reading assignments" are better off in some kind of teaching forum.
However a question along the lines of "what are the pricing logic's options when market data admits arbitrage", not related to teaching, might be on-topic here.

we don't have a quant education se...we can't possibly have an education se for every single non-education academic se besides academia se if they aren't so popular yet right? i figure maths se and computer science se are so popular that they got their own spin offs. but quant se? did it even graduate yet?

@BCLC I suggest you completely re-edit your question leaving it on-topic, like, what can pricing logic do when market data admits arbitrage, and de-emphasize the off-topic context (that it arose as an exam question), then it might get re-opened.

Example of teaching forum please?
